# Get user ID and parse into session variable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication

I am working on an asp.net project in which I am trying to return the user ID of the current logged in use. I have written the user login in C# as I **cannot* use the asp built in control due to other constraints. 
I want to get the user ID from a remote SQL database and then use it as a variable for another function. This is so I can assign the userID to the questionnaire that is being created in the function below. I have tried using the `membership.getUser` but with no luck.

EDIT: When I run the project I get the error **"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** which is pointing at `string UserID = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString()`

**new_questionnaire.aspx.cs** (shortened)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using Questionnaire;

    public partial class new_questionnaire : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        OsqarSQL sendData;

            protected void NewQnrButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Check if the input fields are empty.
                if (QuestionnaireName.Text == "" || CustomerID.Text == "" || NumberOfQuest.Text == "")
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Input fields cannot be blank";
                }
                // Parse input values to OscarSQL.
                else
                {
                    MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();
                    string userID = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
                    int testRet = sendData.InsertQuestionnaire(QuestionnaireName.Text, Int32.Parse(userID), Int32.Parse(NumberOfQuest.Text));
                    Session["QuestionnaireID"] = testRet;
                    Session["QuestionnaireName"] = QuestionnaireName.Text;
                    Response.Redirect("~/buildq/add_questions.aspx");
                }

            } // End NewQNRButton_Click

        } // End new_questionnaire
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is not working? You need to be more specific

Comment: @leppie: ok, english is not my native language. Beside that, Jakub has asked it already :)

Comment: @JakubKonecki please see the edits above.

Answer (score 2):

Check `Membership.GetUser()` returning not `null` user.  if returning user object is null means there is no logged in user. you may need to redirect back to login page and authenticate user.

And also `ProviderUserKey` may be a `GUID` not an integer then you can't convert it to a integer.

```
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();
if(null != membershipUser)
{
    int userId;
    if(int.TryParse(membershipUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString(), out userId)
    {
        int testRet = sendData.InsertQuestionnaire(QuestionnaireName.Text, userId, Int32.Parse(NumberOfQuest.Text));
        Session["QuestionnaireID"] = testRet;
        Session["QuestionnaireName"] = QuestionnaireName.Text;
        Response.Redirect("~/buildq/add_questions.aspx");
    }

}else
{
    // user may not login , redirrect to login page
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This project was put on hold for a few weeks.
I have tried implementing your solution however it appears that the second if statement fails and returns the user to the login page.
Breakpoints show that it fails on the statement 
`if(null != membershipUser)` however the user is logged in.
What could be going wrong?
Thanks